# ASP.NET Universal Providers - Roleprovider does not cache roles in cookie

Tags: cookies, roles, membership, roleprovider

Ironically my role provider does not cache the roles in a cookie anymore. That was working earlier. Unfortunately i have noticed that only now, so i cannot say what causes the problem. But i think it has to do with the update to the new version 1.2 of the universal providers (released on 16th august).

My config for the roleprovider looks like:

```
 <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName="X_Roles" 
cookiePath="/" cookieProtection="All" cookieRequireSSL="true" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieTimeout="1440" 
createPersistentCookie="false" domain="" maxCachedResults="25" defaultProvider="XManager_RoleProvider">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="XManager_RoleProvider" type="ManagersX.XManager_RoleProvider, AssemblyX" 
connectionStringName="XEntities" applicationName="/" rolesTableName="Roles" roleMembershipsTableName="Users_Roles"/>
</providers>
</roleManager>
```

Everything is working fine with the rolemanager (loginviews, menu with sitemaptrimming etc.), but it is only not caching the roles anymore. The membership provider, sessionstate etc. are also working fine and the cookies of them are set correctly.

All properties of the static Roles-class are correctly set and everything in Httpcontext (IsSecureConnection etc.) is also correct.

The roles cookie was set earlier, but not anymore. I hope anybody can help me with my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

HeManNew

**UPDATE:**
Has nobody got the same problem or a tip for me, please?

Comment: Same problem here for me. I'm tempted to implement my own Caching using HttpRuntime.Cache.

Comment: Thanks for that tip Kwex - now i know that i am not alone and that is for sure a problem with the library not elsewhere in project. Can you say how you implemented it, please?

Comment: Please find my response below.

Comment: I also experienced that the caching suddenly stopped working, without me changing anything except perhaps updates to the .NET Framework.  I had to implement caching myself also... but I don't think this should be the answer.  The answer should be how to use the supposed built-in caching through the web.config for the role provider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below are the details of the Custom Role Provider I wrote that uses proper caching and doesn't hit the database on each page load.

============= My Code-Behind file ===============

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MyProject.Providers
{
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        #region Properties

        private static readonly object LockObject = new object();
        private int _cacheTimeoutInMinutes = 0;

        #endregion

        #region Overrides of RoleProvider

        public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
        {
            // Set Properties
            ApplicationName = config["applicationName"];
            _cacheTimeoutInMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(config["cacheTimeoutInMinutes"]);

            // Call base method
            base.Initialize(name, config);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the specified user is in the specified role for the configured applicationName.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the specified user is in the specified role for the configured applicationName; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="username">The user name to search for.</param><param name="roleName">The role to search in.</param>
        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            // Get Roles
            var userRoles = GetRolesForUser(username);

            // Return if exists
            return userRoles.Contains(roleName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a list of the roles that a specified user is in for the configured applicationName.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A string array containing the names of all the roles that the specified user is in for the configured applicationName.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="username">The user to return a list of roles for.</param>
        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            // Return if User is not authenticated
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return null;

            // Return if present in Cache
            var cacheKey = string.format("UserRoles_{0}", username);
            if (HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] != null) return (string[]) HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];

            // Vars
            var userRoles = new List<string>();
            var sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>
                                {
                                    new SqlParameter("@ApplicationName", ApplicationName),
                                    new SqlParameter("@UserName", username)
                                };

            lock (LockObject)
            {
                // Run Stored Proc << Replace this block with your own Database Call Methods >>
                using (IDataReader dr =
                    BaseDatabase.ExecuteDataReader("aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetRolesForUser", sqlParams.ToArray(),
                                                   Constants.DatabaseConnectionName) as SqlDataReader)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        userRoles.Add(dr["RoleName"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            // Store in Cache and expire after set minutes
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, userRoles.ToArray(), null,
                                     DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_cacheTimeoutInMinutes), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

            // Return
            return userRoles.ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the application to store and retrieve role information for.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The name of the application to store and retrieve role information for.
        /// </returns>
        public override sealed string ApplicationName { get; set; }

        // I skipped the other methods as they do not apply to this scenario

        #endregion
    }
}
```

============= End of My Code-Behind file ===============

============= My Web.Config file =======================

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleManager">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SqlRoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="AspnetDbConnection" applicationName="MyApplication"/>
    <add name="CustomRoleManager" type="MyProject.Providers.CustomRoleProvider" connectionStringName="AspnetDbConnection" applicationName="MyApplication" cacheTimeoutInMinutes="30" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

============= End of My Web.Config file ================

The cache is set to expire automatically after every 30 minutes. You can modify this as you deem fit.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ;) ! I will implement the caching like you did. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, but I was able to find a MS KB article that seems to have fixed it. I installed the patch and the cookie reappeared.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750147

See the section: ASP.Net Issue 4.

Hopefully that helps someone else!